# The origin of the word Teffilin

Tags: words, tefilin

We know that the word תפילין appears nowhere in the Tanach. On the other hand, the only meaning of "תפילה" in Tanach is "a prayer" (see [Sefaria search תפילה"](https://www.sefaria.org/search?q=%D7%AA%D7%A4%D7%99%D7%9C%D7%94&tab=text&tpathFilters=Tanakh&tvar=1&tsort=chronological&svar=1&ssort=relevance)).

Seemingly, because the commandment of Teffilin is Biblical, it has no connection with the Rabbinic obligation of fixed prayers, to necessitate the word תפילין (single תפילה").

The "[Dictionary of Jewish Usage: A Guide to the Use of Jewish Terms](https://books.google.co.il/books?id=Nk_RFL9LYg0C&pg=PA165&redir_esc=y#v=onepage&q&f=false)" (quoted on [WIKI](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tefillin#Etymology)) says:
[image]

I thought I could give it a try here, to find a better explanation of the origin of the word "תפילין".

Comment: "because the commandment of Teffilin is Biblical, it has no connection with the Rabbinic obligation of fixed prayers" I don't understand why biblical commandments can't have connections to rabbinic commandments, but anyway why can't it be related to the biblical command of unfixed prayer?

Comment: @DoubleAA Unlike Tzitzit, which are originally "גדילים" that are hard linked to ציציות of clothes, Teffilin is not linked to the prayers, you don't wear them FOR the prayer or ONLY during the prayer, or somehow connected. So there's no real *necessity* IMHO to call it תפילין.

Comment: @DoubleAA For example, if you say, "I hold my Tzitzis" it's pretty obvious what you do, but if you say "I hold my תפילה" it sounds weird.

Comment: That's fine but it has nothing to do with biblical vs rabbinic

Comment: [ונקראים תפילין לשון פלילה](https://www.sefaria.org/Tur%2C_Orach_Chaim.25?vhe=Orach_Chaim,_Vilna,_1923&lang=bi)

Comment: [ונקראו הדיינים 'פלילים', מפני שהוא שופט במחשבתו; דבר זה כך הוא, ודבר זה כך הוא. וזהו לשון 'תפילין' גם כן, מלשון מחשבה, שהתפילין הם לאות ולזכרון בין עיניו (שמות יג, ט), והזכרון הוא במחשבה](https://www.sefaria.org/Be'er_HaGolah%2C_Well_4.2.2?vhe=Be%27er_HaGolah,_with_footnotes_and_annotations_by_Rabbi_Yehoshua_D._Hartman,_Machon_Yerushalyim,_2002&lang=bi)

Comment: [וזה תפילין לשון דביקות כי תשובה בא מבינה דכתיב יבין ושב ובינה וחכמה הוא רעין דלא אתפרשן כדאיתא בספר יצירה הבן בחכמה וחכם בבינה וזה לשון תפילין](https://www.sefaria.org/Divrei_Emet%2C_Divrei_Emet_on_Torah%2C_Shoftim?vhe=Divrei_Emet,_Zalkowa_1801&lang=bi)

Comment: @Anonymus wouldn't it make more sense to call them פלילין if the origin is פלילים?

Comment: https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/114595/why-are-tefilin-never-mentioned-anywhere-in-nach Definitely a מצוה מן המובחר to wear all day but was it ever done universally? Also, my research today has not found any talmudic sources that unambiguously require it as opposed to "allow it" to be worn all day (and not at night) or view it as a midas chassidus.

Comment: Got sidetracked.and forgot the question: Many words for mitzvos or mitzvah-related terms have rabbinic origins e.g. kiddushin vs. Eirusin (see gemara kiddushin 2b), rosh hashana vs chag hazikaron and many other that I'm not remembering right now. IIRC there are also some that were renamed after a rabbinic requirement associated with them as well. Would be worth asking a separate question on that.

Comment: @Anonymus One is called תפילה, so the excuses are purely metaphorical.