# Evidence for rabbis wearing Tefilin all day

Tags: history, tefilin

Is there historical, archeological, or written evidence for rabbis ever wearing Tefilin all day, outside Jewish sources?

Comment: related  https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/78795/759 https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/114595/759 https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/9462/759

Comment: Why specially rabbis?